# Temporal cross-validation in forecasting: model selection, hyperparameter tuning and comparison to independent forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, model-selection, hyperparameter

I'm mainly working with time-series models and want to make sure to build the correct model selection process.

Let's consider a forecasting problem and I have two model candiates, Model A and Model B. For both, I'll do hyperparameter tuning using temporal CV (sliding or exapnding window approach). In the end, I need the best model and compare it to an external, independent forecast produced by somebody else with an unknown process.
Since the hyperparameters cannot be retuned whenever new data streams in on the live-system, using a nested-CV approach is not appropriate in my opinion.

The process I've come up with looks like this:

1. Split the data into train and test, with test being the most recent data (temporal order is conserved).
2. Use the temporal CV on the train data to obtain the optimal hyperparameters for both Model A and Model B.
3. Run the temporal CV on the test data (that is, the forecasts are produced for dates available in the test data) to obtain the generalization error of the optimized models, which can then be compared to the external forecast.

What is unclear to me is whether to choose the tuned Model A or Model B based on the CV error obtained from 2) or from 3). That is, do I use the test or the validation error for the final model selection?

My second problem is that using this approach, I loose the most recent data for model optimization because they represent the test data. So while I capture the generalization error well, I might obtain an error from concept drift that I cannot measure nor detect.
Yet, if I left out step 3), I would compare the CV error from 2) with the accuracy of the external forecast. But this is not completely fair sincethe CV error from 2) is most likely too optimistic due to the process of hyperparameter tuning.

I would love to hear some opinions on these points as I could not find a detailed discussion on this anywhere. If anything is unclear, please let me know!

Comment: Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Good question that touches a fundamental subject in ML. We have to bare in mind that we try to imitate real life, and by real life I mean real-life *knowledge* at some future point in time.
Thus, we use the validation scores (either if they were achieved using a validation set or a cross validation) so not to overfit the test set, or contaminate the setup (in an experimental sense).
We train the model on the training set, choosing the right hyper-parameters on the validation set (by "checking" how they are expected to perform on real-life), and then we get a better estimate, if you'd like, of the expected performance, using the scores on test set. In some test sets in real life (when doing POCs) your test set don't even have labels.
Finally, we want to deliver a model, and we want it to be aware of all the corner cases that might appear in the data. At this point, we might want to retrain on the entire labeled data, using the best hyper-parameters that were found, and the expectation to see a certain performance level, given that the same distribution on later points in time is preserved.

Notice that I didn't specify or treated the fact that your data is time-series. Now to be specific about your questions.

> What is unclear to me is whether to choose the tuned Model A or Model B based on the CV error obtained from 2) or from 3).

You choose the model that performed the best on the way you constructed your validation criteria. You should not contaminate the experiment by looking at the test set at this point.

> My second problem is that using this approach, I loose the most recent data for model optimization because they represent the test data.

That is also a good point. When you deliver the model to the inference stage (which come *after* you finished your entire model construction and you have (1) model (weights and best-hyperparameters), (2) some understanding regards future performance), you retrain your model on the entire labeled data, using the hyper parameters that you've found. This is a valid process because you don't expect (or, you assume, to be specific), that the test set was sampled from the same distribution as your validation set.